# App distribution: right shebang in the script

Tags: perl, perl-module, shebang

What "shebang" line should I use in the script of an "App::Name" module? 
I have searched in "App" modules where I have found often these two:

```
#!perl
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Is `#!/usr/bin/env perl` the better choice?

---

I think I have used the wrong word, I should have said "distribution" instead of "module".

Comment: I'm not actually sure it matters in a module - the caller will have a shebang path defining an interpreter, and that'll be the one that gets used.

Comment: As the answers point out, you don't need a `#!` line in a module -- but [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) may be indirectly relevant.

Comment: Just `#!perl` is not portable.  I know it used to work on some version of MacPerl but a proper shebang contains the actual full path to the interpreter.

Comment: @KeithThompson The question you link to compares `env` with an absolute path.  I'm not seeing anything comparing the simple `perl` command to `env`.

Comment: @tjd: Which is why I said it's *indirectly* relevant.

Comment: @tripleee: `#!perl` doesn't tell the OS how to execute the script the way `#!/usr/bin/perl` does, but the Perl interpreter itself recognizes it. `#!perl` by itself probably isn't useful, but you can add command-line options. `perldoc perlrun` for details. But I don't think it has any effect for module files.

Answer (score 4):

1. A shebang line in a module is useful on *nix OSs if you've written it to be a [Modulino](http://www.masteringperl.org/category/chapters/modulinos/), which can make testing easier.
2. A shebang line in code you don't intend to be directly executable can also be a useful hint for an editor's language support capabilities if it doesn't recognize the file extension.

As to the instances of `#!perl`, as this isn't portable for execution, this is probably of the second variety; there for the editor.